# not submitted app for review

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I wanted to submit my app for the App Store on iTunes Connect, but whatever I do I got this last message telling me there are still one or more errors on the page.

*Things I completed till now:*

> 1. Filled app information.
> 2. Filled contact information.
> 3. Uploaded screenshots for all supported sizes.
> 4. Uploaded binary / selected on iTunes connect.
> 5. Filled rating form.
> 6. Changes done for "Pricing".
> 7. Change app versions.

*Screenshot of my error in iTunes connect:*

[image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step on [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html)

One thing you might be missing is archiving the app on Xcode and uploading through there to iTunesConnect.

If you need more info on how to do that I will update my answer

Comment: build option not there.

Comment: you need to have an iPhone/iPad attached to the computer and the target needs to point to the device

Answer (score 1):

**Step - 1** Your application should now be tested and ready to roll. All you need to do is submit to Apple for approval. This is surprisingly easy considering what you’ve been through already.
Go to Xcode and choose Generic iOS Device in the scheme chooser:

[image]

**Step - 2** choose Product\Archive:

[image]

**Step - 3** Xcode should have already validated against most problems. So save yourself some time and click Upload to App Store…

[image]

**Step - 4** Select your iOS Developer credentials and click Choose:

[image]

**Step - 5** Next, you will be shown the app to upload. Click Upload:

[image]

**Step - 6** Your app will start uploading to iTunes Connect. Various windows will update with messages as code is compiled, verified and code-signed. When the upload finishes, you should see the following message:

[image]

**Step - 7** You now just have a couple of quick steps to submit the app. Switch back to iTunes Connect and scroll down to the Build area you skipped earlier and click Select a build before you submit your app:

[image]

**Step - 8** Select the build Xcode just uploaded and click Done:

[image]

**Step - 9** Click Submit for Review:

[image]

Comment: @Ravi You should not disclose details of your application, profile details etc, you should add a blur to hide the details, you, or your company might be having a NDA with your client, FYI.